# Ifelse applied to an interval of columns, but keeping all the other columns

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I would like to use the `ifelse` function to attribute new `values` to a set of `columns` in a `df`. The real `df` has >200 `columns`, so I can't state the names of the `columns`, instead, I need to specify the interval of `columns` (e.g. `2:205`).

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(123, 121, 120, 124, 125), y=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1), z=c(0,0, 0, 0, 1))
df
    x y z
1 123 1 0
2 121 0 0
3 120 0 0
4 124 0 0
5 125 1 1
```

However, when I do specify the interval of columns, the first `column` is skipped. How can I keep the first `column` unchanged?

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(ifelse(df[2:3] == 1, 2, 0))
df2
  y z
1 2 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 2 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not simply `cbind()` your columns after you run `ifelse()` like this: `df3 <- cbind(x=df[,1], df2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples solution would be to use your current code, but reassign your output to the same subset of the original data with `df[2:3]<-function(df[2:3])`:

```
df2<-df
df2[2:3]<- as.data.frame(ifelse(df[2:3] == 1, 2, 0))
df2
    x y z
1 123 2 0
2 121 0 0
3 120 0 0
4 124 0 0
5 125 2 2
```

Or we can use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(2:3, ~ifelse(.x==1, 2, 0)))

    x y z
1 123 2 0
2 121 0 0
3 120 0 0
4 124 0 0
5 125 2 2
```